# Why is the AI repeating the function?

Tags: python, function

When I say "Friday" "take a screenshot" it takes a screenshot. Everything okay. But it repeats this function. It says "I took a screenshot of your main screen" and takes a screenshot again and again. It is only this function. I tried with other functions but there it repeats it only one time - that is an other problem to fix.

Main code:

```
import functions as FF
import speakandrecognizefunctions as SRF
import datetime
import pyautogui

WAKE_WORD = "friday"
USER = "user"
PATH = "C://MeineDirection"

def success():
    print("Succesful")

def screenshot():
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    filename = str(date).replace(":", "-") + "-screenshot.png"
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    img.save(f'{PATH}//screenshots//{filename}')
    SRF.speak("I took a screenshot of your main screen " + USER)

while True:
    text = SRF.takecommandbackground()

    if text.count(WAKE_WORD) > 0:

        SRF.speak("Im listening " + USER)
        print("\nListening....")

    
        text = SRF.takecommand()

        SCREENSHOT_STRS = ["make a screenshot", "take a screenshot", "screenshot"]
        for phrase in SCREENSHOT_STRS:
            if phrase in text:
                screenshot()
                success()
```

Speech recognition code:

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import config



engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)



WAKE_WORD = "friday"

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def takecommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        #r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.5)
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)

        except Exception as e:
            speak("I didnt get that !!")
            print(f"Exception. Say {WAKE_WORD} and try again " + str(e))
            pass

    return said.lower()


def takecommandbackground():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.3)
        #print("Ready")
        audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=4)

        try:
            # print("Recognizing....")
            query = r.recognize_google(audio)
            #print("user said : ", query)
            # speak(query)

        except Exception:
            #print("Say that again please !! ")
            return "none"
    return query.lower()
```

Comment: If you say "take a screenshot", *two* of the strings in `SCREENSHOT_STRS` are found within it.  You need to break out of that loop upon success.

Answer (score 1):

Easy "take a screenshot" will trigger for "take a screenshot" & "screenshot"
Take out "screenshot" from `SCREENSHOT_STRS` and see what . If that works then you want to break the loop as @jasonharper suggested

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the Loop, because it loops all the Time, or you clear the Text Var.